# How to add android aar to a Cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova, build, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have added an android aar to my Cordova project. With android studio new module function. But when I build my cordova project in command line with the command "cordova build android" cordova is removing the include in the settings.gradle file.
before build:

```
  include ":", ":sdk"
```

after build:

```
  include ":"
```

Then my app crashes because it's missing classes from the sdk I'm using. When I build the project with Android Studio everything is working fine.